# Any way to check if innodb_file_per_table is set in MYSQL 5.5 per table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema, mysql-5.5

I want to check if `innodb_file_per_table` is set (i.e `.ibd` is created) for each database tables using `MYSQL-5.5`  query.

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME, SPACE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES;
```

The `SPACE` will be 0 for the global tablespace (ibdata1) and some greater number for file-per-table tablespaces.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-sys-tables-table.html

---

Since you are using MySQL 5.5, the above solution will not work. In MySQL 5.5, you can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, SPACE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU
WHERE TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'SYS%';
```

Again, SPACE is 0 for the global tablespace, and greater integers for file-per-table.

With the caveat that it only reports on tables that have pages in the buffer pool. If you haven't queried a table, it will have no pages in the buffer pool LRU, and the query will not report any result for that table.

The only other solution is to use `ls` in the data directory. :-)

Comment: getting error `ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES' in information_schema`

Comment: It was introduced in MySQL 5.6 and in Percona Server 5.1.

Comment: Hey I want solution in MySQL 5.5

Comment: it's `SELECT NAME, SPACE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLES;` in MySQL 8

Answer (score 65):

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| innodb_file_per_table | ON    |
+-----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This just tells you if the setting is enabled. Any tables that were created before enabling file_per_table will still be in the global tablespace.
My interpretation of the question is they want to know which tables actually do have their own file (they were created after enabling file_per_table).